# 'data' variable is undefined for JSTree .bind("hover_node.jstree", function (e, data) event

Tags: jquery, jstree

The `data` variable in `function (e, data)` is always returning undefined. IIRC it should be the node that is hovered on.

```
$("#search").bind("hover_node.jstree", function (e, data) {

    console.log(data); //always 'undefined'

    //This is what I wish would work:
    var node = data.rslt.obj, // the hovered node 
     tree_instance = data.inst; // tree instance

    tree_instance.open_node(node);

}).jstree({
    "core": {
        ...
});
```

Any ideas on what's wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a workaround since `hover_node` was sporadic at best. I'm using the json_data plugin so nodes are created dynamically. So every time a node opens, check its children as leaf nodes, then add the appropriate CSS. In this case, I wanted to add a "Go" button that appears over the leaf node that is hovered.

```js
.bind("after_open.jstree", function (data) {

    refreshGoButtonHover();

});
```

...

```
function refreshGoButtonHover() {

    $('.jstree-leaf').mouseover(function () {
        $(this).find('.go_button').addClass('visible');
    });

    $('.jstree-leaf').mouseout(function () {
        $(this).find('.go_button').removeClass('visible');
    });
}
```